# Move selected pixels on multiple layers simultaneously on GIMP

Tags: gimp, layers, texture, image-editing

I have several images of the same brick texture but with different color values for different purposes like this:

[image] [image] [image]

They are in reality much bigger and there are 10 images in total.

For my project I need to make a new texture where I line up all the short bricks in this pattern:

[image]

But my problem is, I need to move each corresponding brick on ALL 10 images in the exact same way so that the resulting 10 texture images all line up perfectly.

If I import all the images as layers, is there a way to move the selected pixels on every layer? If not, is there any other free software I can use?

EDIT: I want to clarify that I do not want to move the whole layer at a time, I want to move the individually selected bricks of the layer. Chain-linking the layers only lets me move the WHOLE layer, not the selected pixels. If I move the selection on a layer, it does not propagate to the other linked layers.

Grouping the layers does not work either. If I select the whole group and try to move the selected pixels (with the selection tool and ctrl+alt) I get the error message: "Cannot modify the pixels of layer groups".

Answer (score 2):

If the things to move are each on their own layer (use the selection to copy/paste them to a new layer if not), then you can [chain-link the layers](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-dialogs-structure.html#gimp-layer-attributes), and move one of them, which will make the other ones move the same way.

Comment: It's also possible to group layers, and change the Move Tool options to "Move the active layer". Then if you select the Group in the layers panel, you can move the whole group of layers at once.

Comment: I don't want to move the WHOLE layer, I want to move the selected parts of the layer.

Comment: @EspenSales - it would better to have different layers for different parts, then you can group them or link them as required.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have more than 400 bricks in the texture. If I make 10 layers for each brick (because the texture has 10 color variations) then I will have 4000 layers. This is quite cumbersome.

Comment: Which is why I said "copy/paste them to a new layer". But IMHO it could be easier to [recreate everything from scratch](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Shower-inspired-of-the-day).

Comment: I have all the 10 color variations in different layers already, if that's what you mean? Also, the texture is a picture of a real brick wall, so it's not as simple as making it all from scratch.

Comment: You can make a selection that covers the bricks you want to move (use Select>Save to channel, and Channel>To selection if necessar), then apply this selection to each layer to copy paste the moved bricks into a new layer (so ten layers in total). Then chain link the layers and move them.

Comment: Ouch, that's a workaround I do not have time for. I'd have to manually make 10 new layers for each brick, move them into a groups, and then move them. That's over 4000 operations! But thanks for the help, though, I appreciate it.

Comment: No, you make one layer for each color, each layer containing the bricks you want to move. And you do the selection only once, and reuse it on each layer.